# Qt QMAKE_POST_LINK command getting mangled

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have this code in my qmake (.pro) file:

```
# Make sure all the slashes are in the correct direction for windows
SOURCE_DIR = $${replace(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, /, \\)}\\resources\\*
TARGET_DIR = $${replace($$quote(DESTDIR), /, \\)}
message (copy1 $$SOURCE_DIR $$TARGET_DIR /y)
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy $$SOURCE_DIR $$TARGET_DIR /y

# vvv THIS WORKS, BUT IS COMMENTED OUT vvv
#message (copy2 C:\\Users\\adadacha\\Desktop\\audioTest\\resources\\* C:\\Users\\adadacha\\Desktop\\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\\targetDbg /y)
#QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy C:\\Users\\adadacha\\Desktop\\audioTest\\resources\\* C:\\Users\\adadacha\\Desktop\\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\\targetDbg /y
```

So basically what this tries to achieve is copy everything from /resources/...

The following is the output I get. The first line is a message() function displaying exactly the command I add to QMAKE_POST_LINK (except I call it copy1 in stead of copy).
Then I see the correct copy... line getting printed by the system so I can see it looks correct. But then I see an error which shows that `\resources\*` has become `\resources*` and seems to have lost the last `\` I don't know why. I have tried to be dilligent with my `/ and \\`...

```
Project MESSAGE: copy1 C:\Users\adadacha\Desktop\audioTest\resources\* C:\Users\adadacha\Desktop\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\targetRel /y
    :
copy C:\Users\adadacha\Desktop\audioTest\resources\* C:\Users\adadacha\Desktop\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\targetDbg /y
Makefile.Debug:167: recipe for target 'targetDbg/TGW2-AudioTest.exe' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, copy C:\Users\adadacha\Desktop\audioTest\resources* C:\Users\adadacha\Desktop\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\targetDbg /y, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can anyone suggest why this is occurring? Note if I copy paste the same output (as in my commented out code) it works and the end is not mangled.

Comment: Try with plain `/` in paths, most Windows tools deal with them correctly.

Comment: Try to use `$$system_path(...)` function instead of your agly `replace`

Comment: Also use `$$QMAKE_COPY` instead of `copy`

Comment: Ok, so... changing the slashes didn't quite work on its own because once I did this the system started to use `cp` instead of `copy`! So then I removed the `/y` since its a copy thing, and changed to use QMAKE_COPY and this also uses `cp -f` (force, which is what I wanted with /y), so then it started to work :) I am confused... what happened to copy and where did `cp` come from? - that's linux. I also added in $$system_path(...) just to be safe, so I have taken all of your comments on board :) If you add them as answers i'll mark them all up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `$$system_path(...)` function instead of your agly `replace`. This takes care about your system pathes.

Also use `$$QMAKE_COPY` instead of `copy`. This is platform independet way copy files with `qmake`.